# Semicolon after class declaration

Tags: ruby, syntax

I thought that Ruby code:

```
class ClassName ..some methods.. end
```

is the same as Java code:

```
class ClassName { ..some methods.. }
```

And if I write in Java:

```
class ClassName; { ..some methods.. }
```

or:

```
class ClassName { ; ..some methods.. }
```

it raises an error. Therefore, I expected that Ruby code:

```
class Dog; end
```

would raise an exception like `unexpected symbol ';'`. However, the Ruby code works. Please explain why it is possible to use a semicolon here, and what `;` means in this context.

Comment: Ruby allows semicolon as statement separator, it just doesn't require it. It is typically enough to just place statements into separate lines.

Comment: About the UPD: Yeah, Ruby is different language than Java with different syntax rules.

Comment: Amadan's comment does answer your original question.

Comment: Ruby != Java. Semicolons are optional, and curly brackets have a different meaning.

Comment: Also, whitespace is (mostly) optional (e.g. you can intent arbitrary amounts, although 2 spaces is the convention) - So your question is like saying "this isn't valid in Python; why does it work in Ruby?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Explain, please, why is it possible to use semicolon here and what does ';' means in these context

Semicolons are optional in ruby. This means that using them is actually valid syntax. Having a newline is enough for the parser to separate statements. In the case you mention the semicolon is required as there is not a newline as a statement separator.

The following are all valid options:

```
class Dog
end

class Dog;
end

class Dog; end
```

The following is invalid (with ruby >= 2.3 this seems to be fine though)

```
class Dog end
```

For class or method definitions with an empty body using one line with a semicolon separator is idiomatic in ruby. If you have a body you'll usually omit the semicolon and place the content on a new line.

> UPD: I thought, that

Java's syntax parser doesn't allow as much flexibility as ruby's parser. A class or method definition in Java is strict syntax which requires a newline after the class name and before the definition body.

Comment: "The following is invalid (with ruby >= 2.3 this seems to be fine though)" - there is almost always an implied statement separator before `end`, even if it looks weird if you're not used to it (and you're not used to it likely because few people write like that; because most people would think it looks weird, and here we go :P ) Some of it was legal even in olden days, but inconsistent (I just checked my 1.9, `class Dog end` and `def bark end` are illegal but `if true; puts "woo" end`, `3.times do puts "moo" end` and `def bark() end` are fine). BTW `def bark end` is still illegal. Go figure.

Comment: The 2.3 change was intentional but experimental. It also makes sense as `module Dog end` was already valid and even for a class requiring a semicolon (or newline) was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Like Java and C, you can use `;` to terminate statements. However, this is only required if you put more than 1 statements on the same line. According to the ruby convention, you should omit writing `;` in all other cases.

For Eg.

`[1, 2, 3].each { |num| incremented = num + 1; puts incremented }` is valid ruby statement.

Similarly you can use the same concept to create classes and methods in ruby.

`class Abc; end` => will create a class named `Abc`

`def abc; end` => will create method named `abc`

All of these above examples are valid ruby statements.